# Unityでクリック+ハイライトできる地図の作成

Tags: unity3d

**Hearts of Iron**や**Plague inc**のような、地図をクリックするとその地域や国がハイライトされるというようなものが作りたいです。

もちろん、UnityAnswersなどでも調べたのですが、英語で書かれてあるためかきちんと理解できません。

どうすれば上のような地図が作れるのでしょうか？ 具体的にお願いします。

Unityのバージョンは5.0.0f4です。

Answer (score 1):

その部分がクリックされたら色を変えればいいです。